# PHP mail function dosen't work

Tags: php, sendmail

I can't find my mistake in the following PHP file. I guess there is a mistake in the POST or SUBMIT action:

```
<?php   

// Initialize all variables
$name = $email = $betreff = $message = $tel = "";
$destination = 'mymailaddress@host.com';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (!empty($_POST["name"])){
        $name = $_POST["name"];
    }

    if (!empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }

    if (!empty($_POST["message"])){
        $message = $_POST["message"];
    }

    if (!empty($_POST["subject"]))  {
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    }

    if (!empty($_POST["tel"]))  {
        $tel = $_POST["tel"];
    }

}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if ($_POST['name'] &&  $_POST['email'] &&  $_POST['message'] !=""){
        mail($destination, $subject, $message."\n \n \n Phone#:".$tel, "From: ".$name."<".$email.">");
        $mailSent = TRUE;
    }

}

if ($mailSent == TRUE){
        echo "Thank you!" ;
    }

?>
```

The corresponding HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="">

Name:*</br>
<input name="name" type="text" size="50" maxlength="60" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>"></br>

E-Mail:*</br>
<input name="email" type="text" size="50" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email);?>"></br>

Phone #:</br>
<input name="tel" type="text" size="50" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($tel);?>"></br>

Subject:</br>
<input name="subject" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($subject);?>"></br>

Message:*</br>
<textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="10" wrap="virtual"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($message);?></textarea></br>

<input type="submit" value="Send">

<submit>
</form>
```

I tried several times, but I never received an email... Any suggestions?

Comment: Run `mailq` to figure out what the sendmail daemon is doing with your messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mail is relying on your conditional statement `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

so give your submit button a name attribute of the same.

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
```

Everything inside that conditional statement is not being executed.

Having used error reporting, would have thrown Undefined index submit...

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

I also noticed a stray `<submit>` tag; you can delete that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

What does the POST array look like? The line above looks like it should be

```
if (isset($_POST['Send']))
```